# Zone Aware Promise with Ionic 5 and Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm new to Promises (usually use Observables) and Ionic.

I have using capacitor, I have stored the user Id in local storage with this:

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';

async storeAuthData(token: string, user: IUserAuth): Promise<void>{

    await Plugins.Storage.set({
        key: '_token',
        value: token
    });

    await Plugins.Storage.set({
        key: '_u',
        value: JSON.stringify(user)
    });
}
```

I want to retrieve the userId from that storage set. I have wrapped my Promise in a return and believe I've done the correct syntax, but when I call this function I get the Zone Aware Promise _state: null info in the console.

```
 async getUserId(): Promise<string> {
    return Plugins.Storage
            .get({key: '_u'})
            .then(userObj => {
                var user = JSON.parse(userObj.value);
                return user.id.toString();
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                return null;
            });
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

calling the `getUserId` func like this:

```
var id = await this.auth.getUserId();
console.log(id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing about promises is that we have to wrap them in async methods.

So your code would be something like this:

```
async storeAuthData(token: string, user: IUserAuth): Promise<void> {
  // now we introduce the await or the code will run out of control
  await Plugins.Storage.set({
    key: '_u',
    value: JSON.stringify(user)
  });

  // same here
  await Plugins.Storage.set({
    key: '_token',
    value: token
  });
}
```

Then retrieving it

```
async getUserId(): Promise <string> {
  return Plugins.Storage
    .get({
      key: '_u'
    })
    .then(userObj => JSON.parse(userObj.value))
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      return null;
    });
}
```

And when we are calling we have to use the *await* keyword too.

Something like this:

```
console.log('userId', await UserService.getUserId())
```

Comment: Hm. I made this modification but calling getUserId() still returns __zone_symbol__value: "879e55ea-0fa4-423a-bae1-7c422cecfd65"

Comment: That's strange. Are you using await when calling getUserId()? Like this: await UserService.getUserId(). Because whenever we're using async methods we have to await for them. I forgot to put the async keyword before getUserId, will update here.

Comment: Updated my post. Actually I'm getting a compile error on using await when calling getUserId(). 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.

Comment: Yeah, you would have to go using async calls until the top level of the module. And if it's in a constructor you can create an async IIFEE function like this: ```contructor ( ) { (async() => await myAsyncFunction())() }```. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE